# Python 2.7 Copy and paste hyperlinked text

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, hyperlink

I am using Python 2.7, Webdriver and Chrome. Manually, I can mouse swipe across text containing a hyperlink on a web page and copy it to the clipboard. How do I do this automatically? I have no issue finding the element containing the hyperlink. I am not trying to find the hyperlink. I am trying to paste it into a web page text box which does not process https://www.python.org/ ">Link within an "a" tag but processes it correctly when pasted from elsewhere i.e. "Link" with embedded href.

Comment: Show code you used so far + `HTML` of anchor and text box

Comment: An example of the anchor and tect box is:<a href=" https://www.python.org/ ">Link</a>

Comment: I do not have any code used so far to answer my question which is: Manually, I can mouse swipe across text containing a hyperlink on a web page and copy it to the clipboard. How do I do this automatically? Once again, I can find the element but don't how to copy it as a whole link with the text and embedded link. If you manually highlight the anchored text and right click, you get the option to copy the link. I don’t need the link. I need to swipe the text and copy it which embeds the link.

Comment: You want just a link text (visible text, like `Link` from specified `<a href=" python.org ">Link</a>`), right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I need to paste it into a Facebook Note which processed html at one time but, unless I am mistaken, does not anymore.

Comment: When you paste the copied text with a link, FB accepts it. If you paste or send_keys the <a href=" python.org ">Link</a> it no longer works (processes the html in to a text link) for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after OP clarifications, it's still hard to understand the exact issue, so I'll try to cover all possible options :)

Suppose we have an anchor element, like `<a href=" python.org ">Link</a>`

We can find this element in such ways

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Link"]')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href=" python.org "]')
```

depending on what information we currently know about the element and what exactly we want to scrap.

Also, we can use index of anchor element `element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[0]`

1) To get value of `href` attribute:

```
value = element.get_attribute('href')
```

Output: `https://python.org`

2) To get value of text node:

```
value = element.text
```

Output: `"Link"`

3) To get complete HTML code of element:

```
value = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

Output: `<a href=" python.org ">Link</a>`

Comment: I apologize, I should not have stated “Yes, that is correct” to your last question. You have spent much time giving a solution to a question that I have not asked. I will open a new question and  try to explain myself better. Please see: 
Python 2.7 Webdriver - Automating mouse copy of an anchor text element.